# Filtering then Iterating through nested django models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got some nested models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class FacetQuestion(models.Model):
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.CharField()

class FacetAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(FacetQuestion)
    answer   = models.CharField()
    subject  = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

I can efficiently get all the answers/questions/categories at least in the view:

```
def detail(request, id):
    facets= models.Category.objects.
    filter(facetquestion__facetanswer__subject='test').
    select_related()
    return render_to_response('test.tpl',
                              dict(facets=facets,
                                   STATIC_URL = settings.STATIC_URL,
                                   MEDIA_URL  = settings.MEDIA_URL),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But when I loop though them in a template, I get everything (not just what I filtered on), because the template makes additional queries for all questions and all answers.  So the template code is definitely bogus:

```
{% for category in answers %}
        {% for q in category.facetquestion_set.all %}
            {% for a in q.facetanswer_set.all %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What's a good pattern for showing a nested set of models in logical order?

```
Category
  Question
    Answer (subject=test)
    Answer (subject=test)
  Question
    Answer (subject=test)
Category
  Question
    Answer (subject=test)
```

I am using django 1.3.  I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442553/avoiding-n1-queries-to-query-model-plus-all-foreignkey-associations), but that one did not include filtering by subject.

Comment: What do you mean "I get everything (not just what I filtered on):"?

Comment: I don't see only answers with subject=2.  I want just answers with subject=2, and their related questions, and the related categories.  If I have 20 categories, but 2 of them have a matching question, I want to have only those two categories.  I suspect my use of category.facetquestion_set.all is throwing things off.

Comment: Then you're not passing the right queryset to your view.

Comment: To add to what marcin said, can we see your view please?

Comment: Added summary of view code.  I've struggled with it, so I've tried a dozen variants of things.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to solve your problem, but I think I can tell you where you went wrong.

With this line

```
answers = models.Category.objects.filter(facetquestion__facetanswer__subject=2)
```

you are selecting all Categories that have one or more questions which have on or more answers that have a `subject == 2`.

When you iterate over the selected categories like this:

```
{% for category in answers %}
    {% for q in category.facetquestion_set.all %}
        {% for a in q.facetanswer_set.all %}
```

in each loop, you issue **another** query that fetches all questions in the category (`category.facetquestion_set.all`) and all answers to that question (`q.facetanswer_set.all`).
Regardless of filters.

You can use this snippet to print the SQL in DEBUG mode and get an idea of what is going on behind the scenes: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/

...and in this case, it will print lots of SELECT, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I've extracted the SQL from the initial queryset, and it's all fine (a single join that results the results I want).  It is my template code that is misguided... DO I have to build the HTML inside my python to avoid the limitations of the django template language?

Comment: As I  said, I do not have a (good) solution to your problem. You might consider creating the structure you want using simple python-objects or nested dictionaries and pass these to your template. That would not be elegant (or reusable) - but might just work fine for a simple project.